# How to get data in XML from a class object?

Tags: android, xml, object, view

I am looking to return strings to an XML from a class in my android application. For example, in an activity, I have a user class that has a display name and a email address. I would like both of these strings to show up in the view but I am not sure (and frankly have no idea what it is called, so I do not know what to search because I am sure this has been answered thousands of times) how to do this. Forwarding me to a thread or some site that explains this process would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should see android data binding http://developer.android.com/tools/data-binding/guide.html